# angle of twist / stress of thin wall having closed section

Tags: structural-engineering

why the mean area enclosed within the boundary of the centerline of tube thickness is (0.035)(0.057) ? Is it wrong ? Shouldnt it be (0.040-0.005-0.005) x ( 0.060 -0.003 -0.0030 = 0.054 ?

Second question , why for the ds it's 2(57) and 2(35) respctively ? what is ds actually ? 
[image: 500]

[image: 498]

[image: 499]

Answer (score 2):

The first question is trivial. The section's ***centerline*** is the line along each face's center. The right and left faces are 5 mm thick, so their centerlines are 2.5 mm from the exterior, and $40 - 2\times2.5 = 35\text{ mm}$. Likewise, the top and bottom faces are 3 mm thick, so their centerlines are 1.5 mm from the exterior, and $60 - 2\times1.5 = 57\text{ mm}$.

For the second one, you need to observe that this is a [line integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_integral), as demonstrated by the $\oint$ symbol. This is a simple one, so you just have to sum the ratio $s/\text{d}t$ for each side of the centerline, where $s$ and $t$ are the length of each centerline segment and the associated thickness, respectively. So that gives you

$$\oint \dfrac{\text{d}s}{t} = \dfrac{35}{3} + \dfrac{57}{5} + \dfrac{35}{3} + \dfrac{57}{5} = 2\left(\dfrac{57}{5} + \dfrac{35}{3}\right)$$

Comment: ok , for the second part , do you mean , there are 4 boundary lines for the rectangle of 57mm and 35 mm , but , how do you get the thickness is 5mm and 3mm from the rectangle of 57mm x 35mm ?why the thickness shouldnt be 3/2 and 5/2 mm now ? Because for the area of 57x 35 mm , the thickness of the 'frame' has been halved , right ?

Comment: @kelvinmacks, because they have nothing to do with each other. The subtraction of 1.5 and 2.5mm from each side was just done to get the centerline, which is a one-dimensional (as in, it's an imaginary series of zero-width lines) representation of the whole section. And then in the second equation that simplified representation is fed the actual thickness to more accurately represent the section.

Comment: And @kelvinmacks, in all honesty, I'm getting the feeling from all your questions that you are skipping all the theory and derivations of equations and simply trying to do the questions. You really shouldn't have these doubts if you actually take the time to understand the theory. And if you do have doubts, feel free to ask them here, but do so pointing to the exact steps in the derivation you don't understand. I've answered quite a few of your questions now, and I honestly get the feeling that I haven't helped you learn anything other than how to do the exact questions you've asked about.